# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: fileUploadListener="#{uploadFileBean.handleFileUpload}"

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload
            mode="advanced"
            fileUploadListener="#{uploadFileBean.handleFileUpload}"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
            auto="true" />
    </h:form>


</h:body>
</html>
```

and this bean:

```
package com.gravitant.cloud.common.jsf.core.beans;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UploadFileBean {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UploadedFile file;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("---uploaded file: " + event.getFile().getFileName());
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

After selecting a specific image to upload, I receive:

```
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: //C:/dev/gravitant/git-repositories/cloudMatrix-team/cloudmatrix-team/CloudMatrixWeb/CloudMatrix-Web/USERAPP/WebContent/userapp-main.jsf @22,18 fileUploadListener="#{uploadFileBean.handleFileUpload}": Method not found: com.gravitant.cloud.common.jsf.core.beans.UploadFileBean@39d02150.handleFileUpload(org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:280) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:759) [jsf-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
```

but I am sure that I correctly put the name of the method.

Is there anything I miss?

I'm using jsf 2.1.6, jboss 7, Primefaces (tested both with 3.4 and 3.5)

Comment: Apart from a in 2 ways completely wrong scope annotation which shouldn't end up in those symptoms, I'm not seeing any possible causes in the information provided so far. Are you absolutely positive you're running the code you think you're running? Bean's constructor is hit in debug and right logger line is printed and such? Clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, the issue I might have is that I'm running this code together with icefaces jars in my lib (my webapp is heavily based on Icefaces but I just need one component from primefaces), but it's very strange for that to be the cause...

Comment: They're definitely the cause. ICEfaces does some (undesired) auto-initialization/modification related to among others forms and file uploads. Remove ICEfaces JARs and you'll see that it works.